# Remove value from different datasets

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have 2 pyspark datasets:

df_1

```
name |   number <Array>
-------------------------
12   |    [1, 2, 3]
-------------------------
34   |    [9, 8, 7]
-------------------------
46   |    [10]
-------------------------
68   |    [2, 88]
-------------------------
```

df_2

```
number_to_be_deleted <String>
------------------
1
------------------
2
------------------
10
------------------
```

I would like to delete numbers of `df_2` if they exist in `df_1`.
In case array will be `empty` I change it's value to `null`.

I used array_remove

```
df = df_1.select(F.array_remove(df_1.number, df_2.number_to_be_deleted)).collect()
```

I got :

> TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable in array_remove

Expected result:

df_1

```
name |   number <Array>
-------------------------
12   |    [3]
-------------------------
34   |    [9, 8, 7]
-------------------------
46   |    null
-------------------------
68   |    [88]
-------------------------
```

Any suggestions, please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join `df1` with `df2` using cross join then use [`array_except`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array_except) to remove the values. Finally, using `when` you can check if the [size](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#size) of the result array is empty to replace it with `null`.

```
df2 = df2.groupBy().agg(collect_list("number_to_be_deleted").alias("to_delete"))

df1.crossJoin(df2).withColumn("number", array_except("number", "to_delete"))\
   .withColumn("number", when(size(col("number")) == 0, lit(None)).otherwise(col("number")))\
   .select("name", "number")\
   .show()

#+----+---------+
#|name|   number|
#+----+---------+
#|  12|      [3]|
#|  34|[9, 8, 7]|
#|  46|     null|
#|  68|     [88]|
#+----+---------+
```

Comment: Could you please give a suggestion about my question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60722258/how-to-use-write-dataframe-pyspark